# how to get data from azure event grid topic

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

How to get data from azure event grid topic

I have added data to azure event grid topic using topic access key and topic endpoint from NodeJS

how can I read the data in topic using NodeJS

Answer (score 0):

- As far as I know for NodeJS azure function event grid trigger is a way to get the events from the event grid.
- So first of all create an event grid , and topic in the event grid . Also create a function app in azure portal.
- Now in the `fucntions` tab click on `create` a pop will appear and then select `` in the list of templates and click `create`

[image]

- Now in the new window which will appear click on `Integration`  and then click on `Event Grid Trigger(eventGridEvent)`  after that a popup will appear in which click on `create Event Grid subscription`

[image]

- A new window will appear where you should fill all the details in the form such as name, event grid name, subscription name, resource group etc.
  [image]

my function code :

```
module.exports = async  function (context, eventGridEvent) {
    context.log(typeof eventGridEvent);
    context.log(eventGridEvent);
};
```

- Now whenever an event is added to event grid it will be received by the trigger where you can add further computation according to your business logic.

Here I have sent two event which are received by the event grid trigger function.

[image]